# Ubuntu16.10 Pc shutdown when headphones jack is plugged

Tags: 16.04, shutdown, 16.10, headphones, headset

I have installed Ubuntu 16.10 on my laptop. Every time I plug in a headset or earphones the system automatically shuts down. I have windows 10 (dual boot with Ubuntu 16.10 in same laptop) and I tested with Windows and that's working fine.

So, how can I fix auto shutdown problem when plugging in earphones or a headset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to disable the power saving mode for Intel HD sounds

1) `sudo gedit /etc/default/tlp`

2) Then replace

```
SOUND_POWER_SAVE_ON_BAT=1
```

with

```
SOUND_POWER_SAVE_ON_BAT=0
```

3) `sudo service tlp restart`

P.S it will also works upto Ubuntu 18.04 (If it was caused by tlp)