# Power Turns Off When I Unplug My Headphones

Tags: 18.04, shutdown, laptop, acer, headphones

My laptop, an [Acer A315-51-564D](https://global-download.acer.com/GDFiles/Document/User%20Manual/User%20Manual_Acer_2.0_A_A.zip?acerid=636564342205468124&Step1=NOTEBOOK&Step2=ASPIRE&Step3=ASPIRE%20A315-51&OS=ALL&LC=en&BC=ACER&SC=EMEA_27) shuts down every time I unplug my headphones.

I have tried the solution given [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/851891/ubuntu16-10-pc-shutdown-when-headphones-jack-is-plugged?rq=1), but my computer did not have any [tlp](https://linrunner.de/en/tlp/tlp.html) file to begin with. Also, this problem happens regardless of whether I am on battery or AC power.

I have Windows 10 on dual-boot; this does not happen in Windows.

So, how do I troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 0):

Is this a PC you built yourself (assembled motherboard, memory, CPU, ...)? If so, I suspect it could be a problem with the wiring between the front panel (which usually has the headphone jack, reset button, some USB ports), and the motherboard. If any of those little DuPont connectors get attached to the wrong pins on the motherboard, you could send spurious reset or off signals to the motherboard when you disconnect your headphones.